# Relaxing continuous differentiability in the inverse function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f$ be a continuous injective function on a ball centered at the origin of $\bf R^n$ into $\bf R^n$.
Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at the origin with non-zero Jacobian determinant.
Denote the inverse of $f$ by $g$. Must $g^\prime(0)$ exist and equal the inverse of the matrix $f^\prime(0)$?
I know this is true if $n = 1$.

Comment: Without the injectivity assumption, there is a standard counterexample with $n=1$. What do you mean when you ask "does the inverse function theorem hold"?

Comment: Second comment: Invariance of domain (which is a rather deep result without $C^1$) *does* tell you that $f$ maps homeomorphically to its image. But, once again, I'm not sure what you're wanting to claim.

Comment: The question is whether the derivative of f-inverse exists at f(0) and equals the inverse of f'(0). I don't know the answer unless n=1.

Comment: OK, I have neither a proof nor a counterexample. The inverse function will be continuous and so if you hypothesize that the inverse is Lipschitz-continuous at $f(0)$, then the usual calculation that appears in the proof of the Inverse Function Theorem will establish that the inverse is differentiable with the obvious derivative. I don't see any reason that the inverse has to be Lipschitz continuous, but I don't have a counterexample at the tip of my fingers.

Comment: I believe I have a proof of this result for all $n$. If anyone is interested, I will post it.

Comment: Give it a shot, @Richard.

Answer (score 0):

First note that by reducing the size of the ball and closing it, we obtain a compact set on which $f$ is continuous and injective.
It follows that $f$ is a homeomorphism on this smaller closed ball.
Thus, $f$ is a homeomorphism on the smaller open ball, so we may as well assume that $f$ is a homeomorphism on the original ball.
WLOG we can also assume that $f(0) = 0$.
Since $f^\prime(0)$ exists, we then have $f(x) = f^\prime(0) x + o(\|x\|)$.
Using the homeomorphic properties of $f$ and the continuity of linear maps, we see that $f^\prime(0)^{-1} y = g(y) + o(\|y\|)$.
It follows that $g^\prime(0) = f^\prime(0)^{-1}$.